# Automatic mount of second drive in 15.04

Tags: 15.04, fstab, automount, drive

I have upgraded my Ubuntu to 15.04 from 14.x and I find that I have to manually mount the secondary drive for it to become operational. This is a pain since my /Downloads folder has been directed (by me) to this drive. There seems to be a way by editing /etc/fstab but I do not recall having to do this in the previous installation. Am I missing a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

The editing of the file ***is*** simple.

- Open a terminal and edit your `fstab`:

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/fstab
  ```
- Add a line, eg:

  ```
  UUID=a61d6eab-d90d-471a-8e9c-e9816b6c90cf /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
  ```
- Open a second terminal and run the command:

  ```
  sudo blkid
  ```

  Here is a sample output

  ```
  % sudo blkid
  /dev/sdb1: UUID="d89ae699-b2e9-4442-a292-4f27d36d3a9a" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="000a178e-01"
  /dev/sdb3: UUID="a61d6eab-d90d-471a-8e9c-e9816b6c90cf" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="000a178e-03"
  /dev/sda1: UUID="d94f4097-91fe-4e96-89b2-7877065d0650" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="00096da5-01"
  ```
- Search your partition in the first column, eg. `/dev/sda2`. Take the `UUID` and replace the `UUID` (without the double quotes) in the added line in your `fstab` file.
- Take the type `TYPE` for the partition and replace the type in the `fstab` file.
- Replace the example `/home` in your `fstab` with your preferred mount point.
- Save the `fstab` file
- Mount the partition with `sudo mount <your_mount_point>`

Answer (score 0):

It should not be difficult to mount your drive through fstab.  Since you can manually mount it, I assume you have a mount point directory for it in /media.  So just add a line to fstab like:

```
UUID=<whatever> <mountpoint> <file system> defaults 0 0
```

then issue the command

```
sudo mount -a
```

Note: you can obtain the UUID by

```
sudo blkid
```