# Move home folder to another drive?

Tags: partitioning, mount, directory, home-directory

I have everything currently installed on a 120GB SSD. I've recently installed a 2nd drive (480 ssd) which I've partitioned for about 90% personal use and 10% in case I add 'other' purposes. I@ve not yet stated a mount point in fstab.

I want to shift my complete home folder to this drive (its main partition).

I know the answer is 'google it', and I've done that but can't seem to get a definitive answer and nothing directly referring to 18.04.

Can someone please point me towards a good guide for doing this? Do I need to boot into a live distro?

Many thanks.

Comment: purhaps this link could help you : https://www.maketecheasier.com/move-home-folder-ubuntu/

Comment: I think this answer to an old question will help you: [Moving HOME from command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21321/move-home-folder-to-second-drive/50539#50539)

Comment: See answer by Steve in https://askubuntu.com/questions/21321/move-home-folder-to-second-drive/50539#50539 that points to the official guide and also recapitulates the steps.

Answer (score 1):

Please keep /home itself at the same disk that has your system files and ONLY move your personal directories. Move the directories in your /home to your new destination and alter `~./config/users-dirs.dirs` to reflect this change.

Reason: in the case your 2nd disk does not mount your /home is not mounted leaving you with a broken system.

> I have not yet stated a mount point in fstab.

You do need to do this first though. Have a look at ...

- [How do I add an additional hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125257/how-do-i-add-an-additional-hard-drive)
- [Adding second hard drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/653396/adding-second-hard-drive)
- [Automatic mount of second drive in 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/631824/automatic-mount-of-second-drive-in-15-04)

Comment: I keep /home inside / (root) but it is tiny as it only has user configuration files, mostly hidden. But all data is in a data partition. I primarily do this as I have multiple installs and want to access same data in all of them. But may want different user settings as I can then test changes without changing main working install. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Comment: That's what I do too. I have hmm 9 different installs now (at work; not just Ubuntu). So much easier to just mount a disk into a linux system with your own data.

Comment: So if I were to mount the 2nd drive at /hdd for example, I'd move my Videos folder to XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="/hdd/Videos"  (after creating that folder folder of course) ?

Comment: @Roger06 yes. I would use /mnt/hdd/Videos (/mnt is for mounting internal disks, /media for external disks) OR use a dedicated directory (my system had a /discworld/ that has all my user dirs (Desktop, Videos etc) and holds all other stuff like backups and vbox containers.

Comment: What have I done wrong?

I've mounted the disk at /mnt/hdd. I've changed the line in my user-dirs.dirs for Videos to XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="/mnt/hdd/Videos". This is the folder I get when I click the 'Videos' link in the side bar of a Files window, but if I click the 'Videos' folder in the main panel of my home folder I still get the old one. I've rebooted.

If I delete the 'old' one with the 'new' one show in the panel?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Changing user-dirs.dirs seems to have no affect. I've also tested in a VM running Mint and it does not change the location of one of the folders. Is there something else that needs to run? Does fstab need another addition?

Thanks

Comment: I can do it if I add the folder as a sym link to the one on the mounted drive - but that doesn't seem right.

Comment: Well I've done it with sym links - doesn't seem quite right but it does the job.